# Is there any way to hide the operation contract tag in the wsdl for WCF soap web service?

Tags: wcf, soap, wsdl, operationcontract

For example, if I have a operation contract as GetData() I dont want it to be in wsdl but the method should be accessible by client using Action Attribute and would be able to be consumed.

Comment: Client can call the service using Action

Answer (score 1):

So the client should just "know" that the service method is there and how to call it?

Anyway [no, you can't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046844/in-wcf-is-there-a-way-to-omit-hide-a-serviceoperation-or-a-datamember-from-th). Save the generated WSDL and XSDs, modify them to remove the information you want to remove and then supply these WSDL and XSD to the client.