# How do I generate WCF proxy code separately for two services residing in one class?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/334554/5740031) I created following class that implements two WCF services:

```
public class WcfEntryPoint : IMyService1, IMyService2
{
    #region IMyService1
    #endregion

    #region IMyService2
    #endregion
}
```

It's hosted in Windows Service. App.config looks like:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="TestWcfProject.WcfEntryPoint" behaviorConfiguration="WcfEntryPointBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/TestWcfProject/service"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <!-- this endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host: http://localhost:8000/TestWcfProject/service  -->
    <endpoint address="Service1" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="TestWcfProject.IMyService1" />
    <endpoint address="Service2" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="TestWcfProject.IMyService2" />
    <!-- the mex endpoint is exposed at http://localhost:8000/TestWcfProject/service/mex -->
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WcfEntryPointBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

In order to use these services from some client application I generate proxy code by the command:

```
SvcUtil.exe http://localhost:8000/TestWcfProject/service?wsdl
```

The problem is that generated WcfEntryPoint.cs contains proxy code for both IMyService1 and IMyService2.

How can I generate proxy code only for `IMyService1` or `IMyService2` but not for both together? I've tried to launch

```
SvcUtil.exe /excludeType:TestWcfProject.IMyService2 http://localhost:8000/TestWcfProject/service?wsdl
```

with no luck.

I know that what I need could be achieved by implementing `IMyService1` and `IMyService2` in two different classes. But for the project it's essential that both services are implemented by the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I generate proxy code only for IMyService1 or IMyService2 but
>   not for both together?

Its not something svcutil supports. However you can change how your service publishes its meta data.

On the service you can:

1. [Hide service operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046844/in-wcf-is-there-a-way-to-omit-hide-a-serviceoperation-or-a-datamember-from-th) from being exposed by the MEX endpoint.
2. Add a second [Custom Mex endpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734656(v=vs.110).aspx) with a path of "Mex2".

Between these two references you should be able to create two custom mex endpoints for the service. Each endpoint publishes a subset of the methods for a particular use case.